# How to integrate a Spring Boot profile with Maven profile?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I am trying to integrate `Spring Boot` profile with `Maven` profile but for some reason always the `default` profile is getting picked up.

**mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=prod (WORKING)**

**Logs:**

```
2019-07-01 17:02:15.013  INFO 21872 --- [           main] com.example.BrowserTest                  : The following profiles are active: prod
2019-07-01 17:02:15.405  INFO 21872 --- [           main] com.example.BrowserTest                  : Started BrowserTest in 0.743 seconds (JVM running for 1.757)
************************************************************************
************************************************************************
Site: https://www.yahoo.com
************************************************************************
************************************************************************
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.509 s - in com.example.BrowserTest
```

**mvn clean test -Prod (DOES NOT WORK, ALWAYS PICKS THE default PROFILE)**

**Logs:**

```
2019-07-01 17:03:20.136  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.example.BrowserTest                  : The following profiles are active: @activatedProperties@
2019-07-01 17:03:20.535  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.example.BrowserTest                  : Started BrowserTest in 0.727 seconds (JVM running for 1.706)
************************************************************************
************************************************************************
Site: http://www.default.com
************************************************************************
************************************************************************
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.456 s - in com.example.BrowserTest
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>profiles-junit-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>profiles-junit-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>dev</profile>
                        <profile>prod</profile>
                    </profiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**src/test/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
site=http://www.default.com
```

**src/test/resources/application-dev.properties**

```
site=https://www.google.com
```

**src/test/resources/application-prod.properties**

```
site=https://www.yahoo.com
```

**BrowserTest.java**

```
public class BrowserTest extends ProfilesJunitDemoApplicationTests {

    @Value("${site}")
    private String site;

    //mvn clean test
    //mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
    //mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
    //mvn clean test -Pprod - NOT WORKING :(
    @Test
    public void homePage() {
        System.out.println("************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Site: " + site);
        System.out.println("************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("************************************************************************");
        assertNotNull(site);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways：

1. Move `src/test/resources/application.properties` to `src/main/resources/application.properties`.
2. Add `testResources`:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: Can you also shed some light on how the `<profiles>` section is linked to the `<configuration>` section under `spring-boot-maven-plugin` ? I have some confusion over there as to why we need to specify default profiles in two difference places.

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation `profiles` is a `java.lang.String[]`

so believe it should be defined:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <profiles>
                    dev,prod
                </profiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

have not tested it but i think it is so, you define all profiles you want active (not that i think you want dev and prod active at the same time).

[Spring boot plugin profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#profiles)

Comment: Does this need to be specified even if we specify `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` ?

Comment: Looked into the documentation link that you put above, you are correct. However my problem got solved by @Bugtaker's response

Answer (score 0):

In the spring boot application, there are several ways to set profiles (dev, uat, prod, etc.)

For exmaple : You can add this in your property file:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Programmatically:

```
SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles("dev");
```

To specify what profiles are active, use this line

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
```

In a Unix environment

```
export spring_profiles_active=dev
```

Running the jar file with the dev profile.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev JARNAME.jar
```

here `JARNAME.jar` means your application's jar name