# Spring boot change pom configuration with active profile

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I was trying to change configuration of the pom based on the active profile (dev, test, qa, prod). but every time it was calling the default one (prod)

I have given the profile info in VM arguments in intellij
**arguments** : -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

**Decleration (in POM.xml)**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <currentRegion>run build_dev</currentRegion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <currentRegion>run build_test</currentRegion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <currentRegion>run build_qa</currentRegion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <currentRegion>run build_prod</currentRegion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Usage(in POM.xml)**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>${currentRegion}</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*Every time, this is retuning run build_prod (the default one)*

Actually i have combined the spring boot and angular for some testing purpose and i want to run the angular on environment with different environment.ts file , when i hardcode the arguments in pom like run build_dev/test it works file , i want to automate it arguments based on the active profile .

Any Suggestions/Solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sprig profiles have nothing to do with maven profiles, it's the same concept in different worlds. You have to add the profile to your maven call, e.g. `maven clean install -P dev`.

Comment: Hi Thanks the reply, it works withs maven clean install -P dev, 
Is there any way we can use spring profile instead of maven profile.
Im ready to change the pom configuration also.

Comment: Well, I haven't worked much with spring boot, more with the old fashioned pattern "web app with spring support", but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56844900/7132739) looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: You can simply define a spring profile during the start of your spring boot app via `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` ... apart from that the build itself should never depending on a profile/environment...

Comment: i tried -Dspring.profiles.active=dev , but still it is going to the prod (the default one).